# code is being executed even when catch block has been called

Tags: java

I have this method .
The issue is that when this condition is met

```
if (bagList==null||bagList.size()<1 && UngarList==null||UngarList.size()<1 )
```

It is going into the catch block here

```
catch (Exception e) {

        this.errorText = e.getMessage().toString();
        info.setErrorText(this.errorText.toString());
        response.setinfo(info);

    }
```

But still it is execuing the next lines that is

```
final boolean toProceedorNot = validate(bagList.toArray(new Bag[bagList.size()]))
```

what is want is if this is met

```
if (bagList==null||bagList.size()<1 && UngarList==null||UngarList.size()<1 )
**then directly return the   response;**
```

This is my method

```
public Response getData(Request request) {

    Info info = new Info();

    Response response = new Response();
    String xmlrequest = request.getxmlMessage();

    HashMap listMap = new HashMap();
    List<Ungar> UngarList = new ArrayList<Ungar>();
    List<Bag> bagList = new ArrayList<Bag>();

    UniverseStaxParser xmlparser = new UniverseStaxParser();
    try {
        listMap = (HashMap) xmlparser.parseData(xmlrequest);

        UngarList = (List<Ungar>) listMap.get("UngarItems");

        bagList = (List<Bag>) listMap.get("bagItems");


        if (bagList==null||bagList.size()<1 && UngarList==null||UngarList.size()<1 )
            throw new Exception("No Valid Data is passed as Input ");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        this.errorText = e.getMessage().toString();
        info.setErrorText(this.errorText.toString());
        response.setinfo(info);

    }

    final boolean toProceedorNot = validate(bagList.toArray(new Bag[bagList.size()]));


    try {
        if (!toProceedorNot) {
            info.setErrorText(errorText);
            response.setinfo(info);

        } else {

            // some logic here goes 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorText = e.getMessage().toString();
        info.setErrorText(errorText);
        response.setinfo(info);
    }



    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why wouldn't it execute those lines? They're outside the `try/catch`, and nothing prevents normal program execution flow.

Unless you return from the method (or otherwise alter control flow) execution will continue at the statement following the `catch` block.

Return the `Response` from the `catch` block if you want to return the response from the catch block.

I'm not convinced that this is a great use of a general-purpose `Exception`, however.

Answer (score 1):

I have to think that you should re-design this portion of your software:

> ```
> if (bagList==null||bagList.size()<1 && UngarList==null||UngarList.size()<1 )
> ```

if `bagList` is `null`, calling methods on it will throw an exception. If `UngarList` is `null`, calling methods on it will throw an exception. There's really no need for that.

There's uncertainty in whether or not these are `null` -- a few lines above, you assign them new values and nearly *immediately* overwrite the references, losing reference to the newly-created objects. That doesn't seem right either.

Figure out which conditions are truly exceptional and which conditions you can expect to happen -- and try to handle the exceptions differently from simple things.

Comment: calling a method of a null object will throw null pointer exception. This is a common mistake made.

Comment: Thank you all very much , i have modified the code kept it under one try block , now its working .